# Hypernym for "input" and "output"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there some hypernym word (or phrase) for "input" and "output"?

Like "sibling" for "brother" and "sister", or "parent" for "mother" and "father"?

In a context of electric schemes.

Comment: The acronym I/O is used a lot...

Comment: Can you give an example for context? I can think of several options that might not be appropriate for all cases.

Comment: I don't know what "electric schemes" means, but *input* and *output* are often used to distinguish *information* travelling in two different directions. So collectively, one could say they're both modes of ***communication***.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Transput**

> <sub>[From Dictionary of Computer Science](http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=U1M3clUwCfEC&pg=PA501&lpg=PA501&dq=Transput+dictionary&source=bl&ots=aTdhnZ5v88&sig=ta4jHUHrguvDWCjiWpgoz_bhT3o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P8FOU4ajLqOf8AH_rIC4CA&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=Transput%20dictionary&f=false)</sub>
>
> a term used to collectively refer to input and output. Synonym: input/output I/O

<sub>However: This term is rarely used. Use other terms that are more specific to your context instead like signal or data.</sub>

Comment: The definition you quote is from input/output... I was really surprised at the existence of _transput_, but I draw the line at abbreviating it to I/O, honestly.

Comment: @oerkelens Can't find a dictionary that doesn't redirect the term to Input/Output, but  [it's not that rare.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transput&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctransput%3B%2Cc0) Anyway, I agree that I/O should be used or some specific term like signal or data, whichever fits the context.

Comment: @oerkelens Found a new source.

Comment: I've been in the computer business for over 30 years and I've never heard "transput". 'Not saying it isn't a real word, but I think few people would recognize it. You'd have to explain it. Almost anyone who's worked with computers or electronics would recognize I/O.

Answer (score 7):

I would actually think of the commonly used [input/output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output), or *I/O* .

Transput may be recognized by some, but I can assure you that plenty of people will not immediately grasp its meaning.

I *do* admit it is not very original :)

Comment: Yes, +1. And I/O is more widely used than *input/output*.

Answer (score 3):

In electrical terms, or at least [electrical engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(electrical_engineering)), a proper term is *signal*.

Comment: thanks, good idea; I'd like to accept this answer too (together with `transput` answer), but I can't accept both